# Xcode osx scroll view

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I am going round in circles trying to get a custom view to scroll correctly.

To simplify this.

I create a new OSX cocoa application.
Go to the xib file, select the window. drag a custom view, then drag a few buttons into it.

Run the program, you have a button in the screen.

Now go back the custom view, select editor -> embed in -> Scroll view

Everything looks fine, and suggests you will have two buttons with scroll bars in the custom view.

Run the program, the custom view shows with scroll bars, but the button do not show.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your instructions I have created and changed the project. No problem.

1. Run in IB your "app", CMD R. The user interface itself can be checked in this way.

If problem remains

1. Check the layer position->Click on the custom View
   Is it possible to Layout->Send to back? If yes, then your button-scrollview is not embedded.
2. Unembed the button, view and repeat the process, by checking in IB if now the interface shows appears correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It was to do with layouts and constraints in the end.